# Examine Indexer

Tags: umbraco

I'm working on an asp.net project and I'm having some issues with changing the Examine Indexer.

I used to have a StandardAnalyzer as an indexer but now I need to use an ArabicAnalyzer as an indexer.
When testing it separately all I done was changing:

```
<add name="EntityIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
supportUnpublished="false"
supportProtected="false"
interval="10"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>
```

With:

```
<add name="EntityIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
supportUnpublished="false"
supportProtected="false"
interval="10"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR, Lucene.Net"/>
```

And it worked properly.
When tried to do the same on my existing project I got the following exception in an YSOD page.

Line 31:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Value cannot be null.

I didn't find a solution for this.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

**Update:**

```
<Examine>
  <ExamineIndexProviders>
    <providers>
      <add name="InternalIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
           supportUnpublished="false"
           supportProtected="true"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>

      <add name="InternalMemberIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoMemberIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
           supportUnpublished="true"
           supportProtected="true"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>

      <add name="EntityIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
             supportUnpublished="false"
             supportProtected="false"
             interval="10"
             analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR, Lucene.Net"/>

    </providers>
  </ExamineIndexProviders>

  <ExamineSearchProviders defaultProvider="ExternalSearcher">
    <providers>
      <add name="InternalSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>

      <add name="ExternalSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine" />

      <add name="InternalMemberSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR, Lucene.Net" enableLeadingWildcards="true"/>

    <add name="EntitySearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
     analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR, Lucene.Net" enableLeadingWildcards="true"/>
    </providers>
  </ExamineSearchProviders>

</Examine>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it fails on an existing project, you may need to delete the existing index and then restart the application.

The indexes are all stored at `~/app_data/Temp/ExamineIndexes/`, so you could just delete the specific index folder from *within* this folder and restart the application. This should prompt Umbraco to start re-indexing the content.

Also, you should also set the `ExamineSearchProvider` too, not just the `ExamineIndexProvider`. This is in the same config file. This ensures that the same `Analyzer` type is used to search the results as is to index them.

**Edit**

Looking at the configuration, you are missing an `Analyzer=""` on the `ExternalSearcher`

**Further edit**

The value `Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR` isn't a valid analyzer value it is just the namespace of an analyzer. I didn't check as I assumed you had, but the value should, in both instances be:

```
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
```

See here: http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d94/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_a_r_1_1_arabic_analyzer.html

Comment: I tried this, same error.
I'm running the project via Visual Studio and after deleting the ~/app_data/Temp/ExamineIndexes/ it didn't re-index, there's no index files right now.

Comment: have you set the other configuration settings for the indexes?

Comment: What do you mean by other configuration settings for the indexes?
I've updated my questions posted the ExamineSettings.config file, please take a look.

Comment: "Looking at the configuration, you are missing an Analyzer="" on the ExternalSearcher" isn't the problem, because it worked fine till now.
adding the ArabicAnalyzer makes the problem, could the ArabicAnalyzer  type making the problem?
Do I need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, What I should've done is changing:

```
<add name="EntityIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
supportUnpublished="false"
supportProtected="false"
interval="10"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR, Lucene.Net"/>
```

with:

```
<add name="EntityIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
supportUnpublished="false"
supportProtected="false"
interval="10"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR.ArabicAnalyzer, Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers"/>
```

And changing the SearchProvider as well.